# Bad character escaping when parsing xml from oracle clob

Tags: xml, oracle

I have a simple table like this:

```
MyTable ( id number(10), configuration CLOB)
```

in oracle 11g (11.2.0.1.0) running on windows.

Now here is my code:

```
declare
vconfiguration clob;

vxml xmltype;
vstring varchar(255);
begin
    select configuration into vconfiguration from mytable where id=1;

    vxml := xmltype(vconfiguration);

    dbms_output.put_line(vconfiguration);

    vstring := vxml.extract('/SmtpConfiguration/From/text()','xmlns="http://www.blabla.com/Drivers/Smtp"').getStringVal();
    dbms_output.put_line('From=' || vstring);
end;
```

Here is the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<SmtpConfiguration
xmlns="http://www.blabla.com/Drivers/Smtp">

<From>"sender1@company.com"</From>
    <MultiRecipients>TO</MultiRecipients>

<ServerAddress>smtp_server1</ServerAddress>
    <ServerPort>25</ServerPort>

<UseAuthentication>false</UseAuthentication>

<UseSSL>false</UseSSL>
</SmtpConfiguration>

From=&quot;sender1@company.com&quot;
```

What I want to do is something like `insert into anothertable(from) values (vstring);`

How to get the value of the From tag with proper " instead of & quot ; ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`extractvalue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28369/xdb04cre.htm#BABDGFFH) instead; [from the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28369/xdb04cre.htm):

> SQL function `extractValue` and `XMLType` method `getStringVal()` differ in their treatment of entity encoding. Function `extractValue` unescapes any encoded entities; method `getStringVal()` returns the data with entity encoding intact.

So instead of calling extract you can do this, which requires a query as it isn't a function PL/SQL recognises natively:

```
select extractValue(vxml, '/SmtpConfiguration/From/text()',
  'xmlns="http://www.blabla.com/Drivers/Smtp"')
into vstring
from dual;
dbms_output.put_line('From=' || vstring);
```

That gives output:

```
From="sender1@company.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with [DBMS_XMLGEN.CONVERT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_xmlgen.htm#i1013173)

```
declare
  vconfiguration clob;

  vxml           xmltype;
  vstring        varchar (255);
begin

  vconfiguration := '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <SmtpConfiguration
    xmlns="http://www.blabla.com/Drivers/Smtp">
    <From>"sender1@company.com"</From>
        <MultiRecipients>TO</MultiRecipients>
    <ServerAddress>smtp_server1</ServerAddress>
        <ServerPort>25</ServerPort>
    <UseAuthentication>false</UseAuthentication>
    <UseSSL>false</UseSSL>
    </SmtpConfiguration>';

  vxml := xmltype (vconfiguration);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (vconfiguration);

  vstring :=
    DBMS_XMLGEN.CONVERT (
      vxml.EXTRACT ('/SmtpConfiguration/From/text()','xmlns="http://www.blabla.com/Drivers/Smtp"').getStringVal ()
     ,DBMS_XMLGEN.ENTITY_DECODE);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('From=' || vstring);
end;
```